# Does `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` provde incorrect height on iOS devices with curved screens?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios17

I'm using `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` and the user info it provides to perform manual keyboard avoidance. Interestingly my method works fine on devices with square screen corners (iPhone SE 3rd Generation) but not on devices with curved corner screens (e.g. iPhone 15 Pro Max). When there's curved corners the height seems to be a bit too large.

I've also tried accounting for the height of the container's bottom safe area but that height didn't exactly match up with the extra height I'm seeing.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    
    @State private var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Test", text: $text)
            Color.red
                .frame(height: keyboardHeight)
        }
        .animation(.default.delay(0), value: keyboardHeight)
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)) {
            keyboardHeight = ($0.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect).height
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)) { _ in
            keyboardHeight = .zero
        }
    }
}
```

Device with rounded corners (bad):
[image]

Device with square corners (good):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of safe area inset at the bottom. Try this:

```swift
GeometryReader { geo in // <- wrap inside GeometryReader
    VStack {
        TextField("Test", text: $text)
            .autocorrectionDisabled(true)
        Color.red
            .frame(height: keyboardHeight)
    }
    .animation(.default.delay(0), value: keyboardHeight)
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)) {
        let height = ($0.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect).height
        keyboardHeight = height - geo.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    }
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)) { _ in
        keyboardHeight = .zero
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @son. I had thought it was that too but it seems to take away too much height. Are you sure?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure. I attached an image as a result.

Comment: I took a closer look, this is pixel perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The extra height comes from the container's safe area, the area that contains the "home swipe bar" on iPhone 15 and other models.

`keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` includes the container's safe area too, but you only ignored the `.keyboard` safe area, and that's why the red area appears higher than what you expect.

One workaround is to ignore all safe areas depending on whether the keyboard is showing.

```
// replace the existing ignoresSafeArea modifier with this:
.ignoresSafeArea(keyboardHeight == 0 ? [] : .all)
```

Alternatively, you can avoid using `NotificationCenter`, and do this in pure SwiftUI. All you need is to read the container safe area, and the total safe area, and subtract one from the other.

```
GeometryReader { total in // this is the total safe area, because no safe area is ignored
    GeometryReader { container in // this is the container safe area, because we ignored the keyboard safe area
        VStack {
            TextField("Test", text: $text)
            Color.red
                // we subtract it here:
                .frame(height: total.safeAreaInsets.bottom - container.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Swweeper. I had thought it was that too but it seems to take away too much height. Are you sure?

Comment: @pinglock yes I am sure. What do you mean by too much height? What height did you expect and what height is produced? Why is it “too much”?

Comment: I took a 2nd closer look, this is pixel perfect. Thanks!